# "Intermediate profile #2 could not be solved. Consider editing the relations and dimensions of the original sketch."

Tags: solidworks

[image: in a separate, new, clean file, it works]this should work.. surely..  I even tested it in another file with another solid body present but not connected..

moved the operation to the very beginning of the design tree, suppressed everything else, same problem.  it must be something about the file..

[image: the problem]

Comment: What *are* your constraints? You need a coincident on the centre point of the circle, and a Peirce on the perimeter.

Comment: did the exact same thing in a clean file, and it works.  so, something is buggered up with the original one.  ..any way to just copy the rest of the part over into the new file?

Comment: yes, everything is the way you said, to the best I can determine.